# Verify Stokes theorem for $F=(x^2-y^2){\bf i}+2xy{\bf j}$ in a rectangular region

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

Verify Stokes theorem for $F=(x^2-y^2){\bf i}+2xy{\bf j}$ in the rectangular region in the $xy$ plane bounded by the lines $x=0,x=a,y=0$ and $y=b$.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I do not have any clue about it. I was looking for some help solving this.

Comment: Do you know what the Stokes theorem says?